# how to parametrize the sides of triangle $P_1P_2P_3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, parametrization

> Let D be triangular path from $P_1(a,a,a)$ to $P_2(b,b,a)$ to
>   $P_3(a,b,b)$ to $(a,a,a)$ and let
>
> $F(x,y,z)=<xy,\tan^{-1}(y),\cos(z)+x>$.Find $\int_D F.dr$?

I'm not getting how to parametrize the sides of triangle $P_1P_2P_3$

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_1$, $P_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f(t)=P_1+t\cdot (P_2-P_1)$ is a parametrization for a line segment. Do that for the three sides of the triangle.